# second page is blank in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

[image]

in my SSRS report the second page is only empty and it continues from 3rd page then there is no blank page

I would like to know what the issue is and how to fix

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: check the width of the body of the report, plus the margins does not exceed the page width or report width.